# $http requests and angular routing based on primary key or url param?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, web, jax-rs, restful-url

I have a relational database from which I retrieve data through a web service. The @GET methods that I defined are based on primary keys. 
For example, for a **team** having a primary key **1**, I use a @GET request http://localhost:8080://teams/1 to get the data related to the team:

```
{
 “id” : “1”,
 “name” : “Barcelona"
}
```

While I am implementing my web app, I faced a conceptual issue. Since I don’t think it is a good practice to let an end user see the primary key id, I kept the requests based on primary key, but, I added an attribute called **uri** to my database table (for Barcelona uri is **bar**, and so on). I am using the **uri** attribute as a parameter in the url. So if a user clicks on Barcelona team image, he will get the url: http://localhost:9000/teams/bar instead of http://localhost:9000/teams/1 while in the internal implementation of the state, I am using the request http://localhost:8080://teams/1 that I already defined in my web service, because at the moment I used a request to get the image of Barcelona, I got the id also that I can pass as parameter to the new request: http://localhost:9000/teams/1

Everything is working fine, but the problem is that if a user enters the url: http://localhost:9000/teams/bar directly in the browser instead of clicking on the Barcelona image, the request won’t be able to work, since the id is not present.

What I want to know is, what is the best practice in this situation?

1. Keeping the behavior as it is?
2. Making requests from database
   based on uri attribute instead of the primary key? If yes, why do I
   use primary key? Why not considering the uri attribute as a primary
   key?
3. What do you suggest?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to create an index in your database for the `uri` field, and then change your web service endpoint to query on the `uri`, instead of the `id`.

Comment: Generally I don't see the harm in showing the primary key in the URL unless is happens to have some significance on its own (ie. bank account number).  If you're concerned about unauthorized access you should be using some server side authentication the verifies that the user is allowed to view the results associated with the primary key.

Comment: Ok guys, suppose you convinced me to base the requests on the uri attribute. So, why do I still need the id attribute as primary key? I omit the id and use the uri attribute as primary key (indexed)?

Comment: @EddyG Having the `uri`-field as a separate field, allows you to change it easily, since you'd still be using the `id` as the foreign key in your relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I will keep the primary key attribute, and I will rebase the $http requests on the uri attribute.

To retrieve the team Barcelona, I use the url http://localhost:9000/teams/bar which will call the web service $http GET method for http://localhost:8080/teams/bar. The primary key (id attribute) is still useful for joins with other relations.

In other cases, where a uri is not valuable, I based the requests on the primary key. For example, a table news has id and description attributes, where no uri is required. Simply I use the id as parameter in the request same as follow: http://localhost:8080/news/123 and http://localhost:9000/news/123 in the web app.